# Vertices overlapping when creating roads with sharp corners by using the array and curve modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, vertices

I have a quick question. I created a plane which is following a path with an array and curve modifier. However, in sharp corners the vertices overlap and the inside of the corner is therefore not really round and smooth. Is there a quick way to fix this or even a completely different way to create something similar?

Thank you! :)

[image: Overlaping Vertices]

Here I adjusted the vertices manually, so that the inside of the corner is rounded and smooth as well, is there an easier way to do this?.
[image: How it should look like]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe tell a bit more about your final goal. A quick fix would be to apply the curve modifier, select all these vertices...

[image]

and merge to the active:

[image]

If you want to keep all your modifiers, assign these vertices to a vertex group, create a *Weld* modifier, choose this vertex group, increase the *Distance* value, it will act like a merge operation:

[image]

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you, the first method works so that the vertices no longer overlap, but the inside of the curve remains very sharp.
If possible, I would like the inside of the curve to be smooth and rounded as well.
I added a picture above to my question, where I adjusted the vertices manually so the inside of the corner is more rounded, is there an easier way to do this?

Overall simply want to create a curvy road and possibly add a curbstone and other details later to the outside of the road.

Cheers :)

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any easy trick, but maybe first try to work with less edges + a Subdivision Surface modifier, it will make the topology easier to work, but maybe tell a bit more about your project, is it a road for example?

Comment: Alright, using less edges and a subdivision surface modifier works a bit better and easier I think but I still have to adjust the corners manually as the inside of the corners are still very sharp. Correct, I want to create a curvy road and later add a curbstone to the edge of the road.